# Checking collisions 2D array connect 4

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d, collision

I'm currently trying to make a 2D connect four game in c#. you know when all 4 colors have to match. Anyway i'm currently trying to get the collisions to work but keep getting an error saying "Index was outside the bounds of the array" Do you know why this is? Thanks

```
private void rules()
{
    int count = 0;

    if (btn[maxR, maxC].BackColor == Color.Red)
    {
        count = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= btn.Length; i++)
    {

        if (btn[maxR, i].BackColor == Color.Red)
        {
            count++;
        }

    }
    if (count >= 4)
    {
        lbl2.Text = "winner";
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the `exception`?  You really should be using a `try/catch` block and capturing the `.Message` property of the `exception` `object`.

Comment: You're trying to access an array either on a negative number or on a number equal to or greater than the array's length. For example, if you declare an array with size [maxR], then the available indexes are 0, 1, 2... maxR-1 (which is maxR entries!), and an access at maxR will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You used:

```
i <= btn.Length
```

and this causes out of range exception, because index starts from zero and ends in `btn.Length-1`.

So use :

```
for (int i = 0; i < btn.Length; i++)
```

P.S: I don't know if is there any logical error.

Comment: Yeah i you're right about that. Now i'm getting error in:

`if (btn[maxR, i].BackColor == Color.Red)
                {
                    count++;
                }`

-_-

Comment: @Das_burr, if you fixed your `i` probelm, check your `maxR` value and if again is out of range, fix it. Also what is your error?

Comment: just the same as before "Index was outside the bounds of the array"